# getting value of the section area?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

[for example this page](https://www.airbnb.com.tr/rooms/12333241?sug=51) if you checkout on responsive you are going to see as soon as page scroll to down.and I'm trying to do with scrollspy (affix fixed navigation) I have bootstrap navbar navigation and on responsive if I'm on related area section of navbar must change with name of related area I design [this page - please check on responsive](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/ammydZ) but I have no any idea how to do it

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span>Section 1</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>

</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p> 
</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>

</div>
```

JS

```
  $("#myNavbar ul>li >a").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#myNavbar ul li a").not(this).removeClass("active");
        var TargetId = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(TargetId).offset().top - 100
        }, 1000, 'swing');
        return false;
    });

         $(window).scroll(function(){     
// close dropdown nav after click on other section  
   $(".navbar-collapse a").click(function () { 
        $(".navbar-collapse").removeClass('in').addClass("collapse");
   }); 



   $(".affix-area").each(function() {
            var sectionID = $(this).attr("id");

            var sectionHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
            var sectionTop = $(this).offset().top - 180 ;

            if ($(window).scrollTop() > sectionTop - 1 && $(window).scrollTop() < sectionTop + sectionHeight - 1) {
                 var uu = $(this).find("h1").text();
                 $(".navbar-header button").text(uu)
                 }
    });
 });
```

Comment: you must share with us what have you tried so far to achieve what you want. we don't provide code. we provide code debugging

Comment: I couldn't nothinh I just trying to understand logic how to do it I am new on jquery that is why I just can show what I want to do sorry about it

Comment: @MihaiT I add my javascript codes

Comment: i posted an answer for you. let me know if that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well. i had some spare time and i made this for you :

see here > **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/r6p1uLsz/3/)**

**first part** of the code gives the `.active` class to the `a` menu element that has been clicked and moves the scroll nicely to the `section` that corresponds to the clicked `a` (menu) element

```
 $("#myNavbar ul>li >a").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#myNavbar ul li a").not(this).removeClass("active");
        var TargetId = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(TargetId).offset().top - 100
        }, 1000, 'swing');
        return false;
    });
```

**second part** finds the section you are in when you scroll down the page, and gets the text of the H1 in that section ( the name of the section) and gives it to the the `button`

```
$(window).scroll(function(){     
// close dropdown nav after click on other section  
   $(".navbar-collapse a").click(function () { 
        $(".navbar-collapse").removeClass('in').addClass("collapse");
   }); 



   $(".section").each(function() {
            var sectionID = $(this).attr("id");

            var sectionHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
            var sectionTop = $(this).offset().top - 180 ;

            if ($(window).scrollTop() > sectionTop - 1 && $(window).scrollTop() < sectionTop + sectionHeight - 1) {
                 var uu = $(this).find("h1").text();
                 $(".navbar-header button").text(uu)
                 }
    });
 });
```

let me know if this is what you were looking for

see also snippet below :

```js
        $("#myNavbar ul>li >a").click(function() {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $("#myNavbar ul li a").not(this).removeClass("active");
            var TargetId = $(this).attr('href');
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(TargetId).offset().top - 100
            }, 1000, 'swing');
            return false;
        });
        
          $(window).scroll(function(){       
$(".navbar-collapse a").click(function () {
            $(".navbar-collapse").removeClass('in').addClass("collapse");
    }); 



           $(".section").each(function() {
                var sectionID = $(this).attr("id");
               
                var sectionHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
                var sectionTop = $(this).offset().top - 180 ;
         
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > sectionTop - 1 && $(window).scrollTop() < sectionTop + sectionHeight - 1) {
                     var uu = $(this).find("h1").text();
                     $(".navbar-header button").show().text(uu)
                     }
            });
 });
```

```css
.navbar-header button { position:fixed;color:#fff;text-align:center;;width:100%;}
.navbar-nav { margin-top:50px;}
#section1 { margin-top:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">Section 1
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="section1" class="section container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>

</div>
<div id="section2" class="section container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p> 
</div>
<div id="section3" class="section container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>

</div>
```

Comment: I checkout demo and yes exactly this is the what I want to do and after break I will check thanks a lot

Comment: it works so great but I couldn't adapted my project but I will achieve I hope :D

Comment: well. why can't you adapt it to your project ? maybe i can help

Comment: this is my page: http://firatabak.com/trying/tur_detay.html
and I will share my code on post  after edit the post

Comment: add class `section` to the sections in HTML

Comment: i mean. instead of `<div id="section1" class="container-fluid">` you should have `<div id="section1" class="section container-fluid">` . so change it in HTML ( for all sections )

Comment: exactly I did as you said wait I will upload project too see

Comment: look on this page: http://firatabak.com/trying/tur_detay.html after scroll page to down on responsive

Comment: well your HTML is too different from the one you shared here. so it's up to you to adapt my code ( which is working with the HTML structure you posted ) to your own HTML structure.

Comment: as I see there is nothing to different ? which one differeny ? I add section class and section id ?

Comment: it's not working because your `.affix-area` is not a `section` but it's the title of the section ( the h4 ). the script uses`outer-height` but because you don't select the whole section, the outer height of the `h4` is too small. i suggest you use `detay-basliklar` instead of `.affix-area` and `h4` instead of `h1` inside the script i gave you

Comment: but I change affix-area as section didn't you see ? :(

Comment: and h4 has been replaced as h1 but if you want I can give you zip file

Comment: write in script inside the IF . `console.log(uu) ` and i will see what's going on

Comment: and console.log nothing printed maybe another functions block your code ?

Comment: now I did it it's work very well but it works after refresh the page on responsive :) how to fix it this issue ?

Comment: well. you have to think that nobody resizes the screen live. i mean, when someone enters from mobile phone...they enter the page automatically at a certain screen size. same for tablet or laptop. so, in real life situations, resizing the screen doesn't happen (99% of cases ) . if you really want that, you should wrap everything in a `$(window).on(resize,function(){` but that will mean that it won't work on refresh and only on resize. that's why....i suggest you leave it as it is. i hope i explained correctly